# How do I create a flag using getopts to run mount command in linux?

Tags: linux, parameters

I need help with my script.
My script is to find if a mount exists. Though I want it run only if I pass a flag using getopts. How can I do that?

```
FS_TO_CHECK="/dev" 

if cat /proc/mounts | grep $FS_TO_CHECK > /dev/null; then
# Filesystem is mounted
else
# Filesystem is not mounted
fi
```

Comment: To avoid the Useless Use of Cat, use `if grep -q "$FS_TO_CHECK" /proc/mounts; then` ... See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example of passing a command line argument:

`$  ./MyScript.sh some_parameter`

MyScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
```

Here's a [simple tutorial on getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial).